# Firefox <input type="file" /> calling jquery val throws "NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR"

Tags: jquery, firefox

Calling following code in Firebug console in firefox throws 1000 "NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR" exception, dont know why and how. tried putting code in the file in the server to avoid different 
domain issue, But that also did not work .

```
$("input[type='file']").val('c:\temp\pngs\UA_text_logo.png');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons browsers forbid you from setting the value of an `input[type='file']` field. So it's normal that you get this error. You are attempting an unauthorized operation. You can read the filename that has been selected by the user but you cannot set its value.

Comment: Is there any firefox setting that can allow me to do this. I am trying to automate testing of the app.

Comment: @AmanT You could write an extension that sets the value to a string you ask it for, and test against a Firefox with that extension installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set value of file input in any browser. In addition you can't invoke click programatically in firefox.